# Distribution of the exponential of a Gamma distributed random variable

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, exponential-family

I have a random variable $X$ that follows a Gamma distribution.

$$ X \sim \text{Gamma}[\alpha, \beta] $$

I want to know the distribution of $Y$, i.e.,

$$ Y = a - \exp\left(-b X\right) $$

Comment: Compute the cumulative distribution function of $Y$, $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y)$ and derive it with repsect to $y$.

Comment: Some conditions on $a$ and $b$ should be imposed to obtain the result.

Comment: @lulufofo Presumably it is reasonable to assume $b >0$.  $Y$ can then take values between $a-1$ and $a$, but I do not see any need to make any assumptions about $a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as mentioned on the comment the easiest way to find the distribution of $Y$ is to calculate the $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)$ since the $Y$ it is a function of $X$ for which you know the distribution.

$$\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)=...= \mathbb{P}(X\leq - \frac{log(a-y)}{b}) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\gamma(\alpha,\beta(-\frac{log(a-y)}{b}))$$

where the $\gamma(\alpha,\beta(-\frac{log(a-y)}{b}))$ is the lower bound incomplete gamma function. Also, in order to find the density of $Y$ you have to calculate the derivative of $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)$ with respect to $y$.

$$f_{Y}(y)=\frac{d}{dy}\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\frac{d}{dy}\gamma(\alpha,\beta(-\frac{log(a-y)}{b}))=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}(-\frac{log(a-y)}{b})^{\alpha-1}e^{\frac{log(a-y)}{b}}\frac{d}{dy}(-\frac{log(a-y)}{b}) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}(-\frac{log(a-y)}{b})^{\alpha-1}e^{\frac{log(a-y)}{b}}\frac{1}{b(a-y)}$$

Now something to take care of is that since we are dealing with a gamma distribution for $X$ in order for the calculations to hold the $-\frac{log(a-y)}{b}$ must be positive, so $Y$ must be great of $a-1$ regardless of the value of $b$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was also carrying out the same after getting the comment. I arrived at the same result except I had a very small mistake. I was wondering if this is a known distribution. Or, similar to one?

Comment: Since there are competing definitions of the Gamma pdf wrt its parameters, it would be helpful (and necessary) to start by specifying which parameterisation you are using (particularly as that chosen in the above does not appear to be the most common one).